# What can I add to a Non-tensorial object to make it transform like a tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

Suppose I have been given the following object :

$${T_{\alpha \beta}}^\gamma=\partial_\alpha {R_\beta}^\gamma$$

I can easily see that this term doesn't transform like a tensor. When I transform this object, I get two parts - one that transforms as a tensor, and another part, that doesn't. The part that doesn't transform as a tensor looks like :

$${R_\beta}^\gamma \left(\frac{\partial^2 x^\beta}{\partial\tilde{x}^{{\alpha^\prime}} \partial\tilde{x}^{{\beta^\prime}}}  \frac{\partial\tilde{x}^{{\gamma^\prime}}}{\partial x^\gamma} + \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial\tilde{x}^{{\alpha^\prime}}} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial\tilde{x}^{{\beta^\prime}}}  \frac{\partial^2\tilde{x}^{{\gamma^\prime}}}{\partial x^\alpha \partial x^\gamma}        \right)$$

I've been asked to add something to the original object, such that under a general transformation, the new object behaves as a tensor. Basically I have to add something to the above object, such that the 'non-tensor' part of the new term cancels out with the 'non-tensor' part of the original term, such that the new object is a tensor.

Is there a general way to guess what the additional term should be, just by looking at how the original object transforms ?

For example, what I did, was to take ${T_{\beta \alpha}}^\gamma$, and subtract this from the original term. This manages to cancel out the first term of the non tensorial part, under a transformation. However the second part remains, and I'm left with :

$${R_m}^\gamma \frac{\partial^2\tilde{x}^{{\gamma^\prime}}}{\partial x^n \partial x^\gamma}\left( \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial\tilde{x}^{{\alpha^\prime}}} \frac{\partial x^m}{\partial\tilde{x}^{{\beta^\prime}}}-\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial\tilde{x}^{{\alpha^\prime}}} \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial\tilde{x}^{{\beta^\prime}}}       \right)$$

This term doesn't cancel out, and this shows that the object ${T_{\alpha\beta}}^\gamma-{T_{\beta\alpha}}^\gamma$ doesn't transform as a tensor either.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed with this problem, and if there is a general way to guess what terms need to be added to make the object a tensor.

Comment: There certainly isn’t a unique answer to the question. For any quantity $Q$, you can add $T-Q$ to it to get a tensor, if $T$ is any tensor.

Comment: @knzhou can you tell me something, is the last expression that I've written equal to 0 ? Since $m$ and $n$ ( ignore $\gamma$ ) for now, are contracted and summed over, I'm led to believe that all the terms would cancel out in the last expression.

Comment: @knzhou also, I don't understand your first comment. If Q is not a tensor, how can I subtract it from a tensor T, to get a tensor ?

Comment: yes exactly, I'm looking for another non-tensor to add to Q, such that the whole thing transforms like a tensor. For example, in case of partial derivatives of vectors, I can add the christoffel connection to make the entire object transform as a tensor. I'm looking for a similar thing, for my object here, which is a partial derivative of a (1,1) tensor.

Comment: Are you familiar with the similar procedure in classical gauge theories?

Comment: @Eletie no I am not. However, I believe that if I add terms to convert this partial derivative to a covariant derivative, the total object would behave as a tensor. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. See [Covariant derivative - Covariant derivative by field type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Covariant_derivative_by_field_type) to see
what terms you need to add.

Comment: It might help to first consider $\partial_\alpha V_\beta$.